# Adding "new line"s to text in text supporting objects (i.e Buttons, Rich Text boxs) both in and out of code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

The other day I made a small program in C# to list things (dynamically via code) in a richtextbox (I could have used a listbox, but I didn't) but everything was on the same line.

Now at time of writing I had placed some text in a button (via the properties panel, and again, this is in C#), and I wanted part of that text to be on the next line (the button being big enough to support two lines)

So it got me wondering: How can you put line breaks in the common text supporting items, both in code and outside of it (via properties window)? By common I mean:

- Rich Text boxes
- Labels
- Buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"\n" is the escaped character for a line break. So code like:

label.Text = "This is a \nbutton";

Should put the word button on a new line.

Edit:

If you want to do it using the properties window in designer, click on the arrow on the far right of the text property field and it will open a small box. If you type multiple lines on that as you would normally (ie actually pressing enter, not using \n) then the component will treat them as new lines and put the new lines in for you.

Comment: Ah very nice. Such a simple answer. Thanks its working fine - However I take it you have to put the text in via code in that case?

Comment: @GarethJones - Should work in designer too, the slash is an escape character

Comment: @Sayse no I tried it - it just put the /n as part of the text

Comment: Instead of using the designer, why don't you edit the code that the designer generates?

Comment: That was something I thought of - I dont mind doing it via code (by an event such as form load) or designer code , I was just wondering if it could also be done by the designer properties

Comment: Just figured out a way to do it. It's been so long since I've used designer that actually opening the designer jogged my memory.

Answer (score 1):

Pharap is correct, but if you want to be a little more precise with code use `Environment.NewLine`. This will match to the newline character based on what platform the code is running on. But if you are lazy "\n" will work 99% percent of the time.

For input into the properties window, there is a small arrow next to the property. Click that and you will get a multi-line text box to enter stuff.

Comment: dam, i had completely forgot about that arrow button! maa... thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

The newline(\n) or with verbatim like this:

```
label1.Text = @"some very  
                                very

                                         very
                          long text";
```

With buttons for example you set the AutoSize property to true:

```
button1.AutoSize = true;
button1.Text = @"some very  
                             very

                                       very
                        long text";
```